# Перерисовка JTree

Tags: java, jtree

Есть `JTree` на основе имплементированной `TreeModel`, которая строится на основе выборки из MySQL-базы. Есть кнопки, по нажатию которых добавляются/удаляются данные в таблицу MySQL. Как делать так, чтобы данные в `JTree` автоматически обновлялись? Методы `revalidate()` и `repaint()` не работают. Работает только `updateUI()`, но его, почему-то, не рекомендуют использовать (кстати второй вопрос - почему не рекомендуют?).

Код:

```
package catalogs;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import main.Global;

/*------Класс окна справочника товаров.------*/
public class ProductsCatalog extends JInternalFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //Объявления компонент окна.
    private JTree groupTree;
    private GroupTreeModel groupTreeModel;
    private JScrollPane groupTreeScrlPane;
    private JButton btnAddGroup;
    private JButton btnDelGroup;
    private ButtonListener btnListener;
    private TreeListener groupTreeListener; 
    private JTable prodTable;
    private ProdTableModel prodTableModel;
    private JScrollPane prodTableScrlPane;
    //Конструктор.
    public ProductsCatalog(){
        Global.DB_NAME = "mydb";                  //УДАЛИТЬ СТРОКУ
        //Инициализация компонент окна.
        //Древо групп товаров.
        groupTreeModel = new GroupTreeModel();
        groupTree = new JTree(groupTreeModel);
        groupTree.setSelectionRow(0);
        groupTreeListener = new TreeListener();
        groupTree.addTreeSelectionListener(groupTreeListener);
        groupTreeScrlPane = new JScrollPane(groupTree);
        groupTreeScrlPane.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 200);
        //Кнопки добавления и удаления групп товаров.
        btnListener = new ButtonListener();
        btnAddGroup = new JButton();
        ImageIcon btnAddGroupIcon = new ImageIcon("images/btnAddGroup.png");
        btnAddGroup.setIcon(btnAddGroupIcon);
        btnAddGroup.addActionListener(btnListener);
        btnAddGroup.setBounds(10, 220, 30, 30);
        btnDelGroup = new JButton();
        ImageIcon btnDelGroupIcon = new ImageIcon("images/btnDelGroup.png");
        btnDelGroup.setIcon(btnDelGroupIcon);
        btnDelGroup.addActionListener(btnListener);
        btnDelGroup.setBounds(50, 220, 30, 30);
        //Таблица товаров.
        prodTableModel = new ProdTableModel();
        prodTable = new JTable(prodTableModel);
        prodTableModel.buildTable(groupTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent());
        prodTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        prodTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        prodTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        prodTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(25);
        prodTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
        prodTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(25);
        prodTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(50);
        prodTableScrlPane = new JScrollPane(prodTable);
        prodTableScrlPane.setBounds(170, 10, 500, 200);
        //Параметры окна.
        this.setTitle("Каталог товаров");
        this.setClosable(true);
        this.setMaximizable(true);
        this.setIconifiable(true);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(700, 350);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(groupTreeScrlPane);
        this.add(btnAddGroup);
        this.add(btnDelGroup);
        this.add(prodTableScrlPane);
    }

/*------Модель дерева.------*/
    private class GroupTreeModel implements TreeModel{
        @Override
        public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
            Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ parent +"'");
            Object parentCode = buf[0][0];
            Object[][] res = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='"+ parentCode +"'");
            return res[index][1];
        }
        @Override
        public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
            Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ parent +"'");
            Object parentCode = buf[0][0];
            Object[][] res = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='"+ parentCode +"'");
            return res.length;
        }
        @Override
        public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
            Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ parent +"'");
            Object parentCode = buf[0][0];
            Object[][] res = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='"+ parentCode +"'");
            int index = 0;
            for(int i =0; i<res.length; i++){
                if(res[i][1].equals(child)) index = i;
            }
            return index;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getRoot() {
            Object[][] res = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='0'");
            return res[0][1];
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf(Object arg0) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath arg0, Object arg1) {}      
    }

/*------Слушатель изменения выбранной строки дерева групп товаров.------*/
    public class TreeListener implements TreeSelectionListener{
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent selection) {
            prodTableModel.buildTable(groupTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent());
            prodTable.revalidate();
            prodTable.repaint();
        }
    }   

/*------Слушатель нажатия кнопок добавления/удаления групп/товаров.------*/
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Если нажата кнопка удаления группы товаров.
            if(e.getSource().equals(btnDelGroup)){
                //Проверяем, пуста ли папка, которую удаляем.
                boolean isEmpty = false;
                Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `id` FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ groupTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent() +"'");
                Object[][] buf2 = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `group`='"+ buf[0][0] +"'");
                Object[][] buf3 = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='"+ buf[0][0] +"'");
                if(buf2.length==0 && buf3.length==0) isEmpty = true;
                //Если выделена группа, она пуста и мы подтверждаем удаление, тогда удаляем.
                if(!groupTree.isSelectionEmpty()){
                    if(isEmpty){
                        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Вы уверены?", "Подтверждение удаления", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)==0){
                            Global.sqlQueryVoid("DELETE FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ groupTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent() +"'");
                            //groupTree.updateUI();
                            groupTree.setVisible(false);
                            groupTree.revalidate();
                            groupTree.repaint();
                            groupTree.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Нельзя удалить эту папку, т.к. она не пуста!", "Ошибка", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);         
                }else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Вы не выбрали ни одну папку!", "Ошибка", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);             
            }
        }       
    }

/*------Модель таблицы.------*/
    public class ProdTableModel implements TableModel{
        //Двумерный массив данных.
        private Object[][] selection = null;
        //Метод построения двумерного массива данных, на основе которого отрисовывается таблица товаров.
        public void buildTable(Object group){
            Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `id` FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ group +"'");
            selection = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `id`, `name`, `unit`, `comments` FROM `product` WHERE `group`='"+ buf[0][0] +"'");
        }       

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colInd) {
            return String.class;
        }
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 4;
        }
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int colInd) {
            String colName ="";
            switch(colInd){
            case 0: colName = "Код"; break;
            case 1: colName = "Наименование"; break;
            case 2: colName = "Ед. изм."; break;
            case 3: colName = "Комментарий"; break;
            }
            return colName;
        }
        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return selection.length;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowInd, int colInd) {
            return selection[rowInd][colInd];
        }
        @Override
        public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {}
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {return false;}
        @Override
        public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {}      
    }
}
```

Comment: Неужели никто не сталкивался с такой задачей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно переложить операции с данными на модель дерева (`GroupTreeModel`), которая будет уведомлять представление (`JTree`) об изменениях. Для этого нужно добавить в `GroupTreeModel` работу слушателей:

```
Set<TreeModelListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

@Override
public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener arg0) {
    listeners.add( arg0 );
}
@Override
public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener arg0) {
    listeners.remove( arg0 );
}
```

и метод удаления:

```
public void removeGroupAtPath( TreePath selectionPath ) {
    Object groupToRemove = selectionPath.getLastPathComponent();
    TreePath pathToParent = selectionPath.getParentPath();
    if ( pathToParent != null ) { // one does not simply remove jtree root node
        Object parent = pathToParent.getLastPathComponent();
        int childIndex = getIndexOfChild( parent, groupToRemove );

        Global.sqlQueryVoid( "DELETE FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='" + groupToRemove + "'" );

        // для события удаления нужен путь к родительскому узлу
        //   индекс удаляемого узла в списке узлов родителя
        //   и удаляемый объект
        fireNodeRemoved( pathToParent, new int[] { childIndex }, new Object[] { groupToRemove } );
    }
}

public void fireNodeRemoved( TreePath parentPath, int[] removedIndexes, Object[] removedChildren ) {
    TreeModelEvent e = new TreeModelEvent( this, parentPath, removedIndexes, removedChildren );
    for ( TreeModelListener l : listeners ) {
        l.treeNodesRemoved( e );
    }
}
```

Дерево само зарегистрируется в списке слушателей модели и при удалении перерисуется, как надо.

Дальше просто в обработчике нажатия можно вызвать метод модели:

```
groupTreeModel.removeGroupAtPath( groupTree.getSelectionPath() );
```

Принудительная перерисовка не требуется.

Comment: Более-менее понял. Попробовал, работает. Спасибо. Хоть и много телодвижений. А как насчет моего второго вопроса: почему не рекомендуют использовать метод updateUI()?

Comment: @Artik `updateUI` пересоздает ui-делегат (компонент, ответственный за отображение `JTree` и обработку действий пользователя), и используется, если вы поменяли Look & Feel целиком или какие-то его параметры. Создание делегата - довольно большая работа (установка слушателей, полная перерисовка), плюс сборщик мусора должен будет когда-то освободить занимаемую старым делегатом память.